# Android browser with fullscreen, night mode and auto-fit text zoom?

Tags: android, web-browser, display, touchscreen, dark-theme

Opera already provides the last 2 features, which I need for reading comfortably. ([Other browsers can auto-fit text while zooming](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212159/what-internet-browsers-are-able-to-provide-text-wrapping-fitting-the-screen-wh), but they lack night mode, and vice-versa: Yandex has fit-text but no night mode, Vivaldi has the night mode, can even hide the the status bar (top bar), but its option to "Force enable zoom" doesn't provide the auto-fitting text.)

***Auto-fit*** changes the number of lines (and of words per line) in order to keep the text in view and allow the flow of reading while zooming in:

[image: ![enter image description here]

while normal zoom (e.g. in Chrome) doesn't change the number of words per line and thus hides part of the words in each line when zooming in:

[image]

***Night mode*** is also present in Opera and other browsers but absent in Chrome:

[image]

***Fullscreen*** would mean hiding the Android top tab and (ideally) also the bottom buttons, the way an ebook reader or a video player does..

---

Are there Android browser that have all these three capabilities?

- auto-fit text when zooming
- night mode setting (dark background for text)
- fullscreen page, like in a pdf or ebook reader, or by hiding at least the top bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result depends on the device. Some devices do not allow the Android buttons to be hidden, and some advanced security permissions need to be enabled. Android 11 seems to have some problems with fullscreen too - [here](https://piunikaweb.com/2020/12/11/navigation-status-bar-occasionally-getting-stuck-in-full-screen-apps-after-android-11-update-youre-not-alone/), [here](https://www.androidheadlines.com/2020/10/android-11-bug-restricts-apps.html).

---

In fact [UC Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl&hl=en&gl=US) has all these three options:

[image]

The fit-text-on-zoom feature has to be enabled in *Settings* (gear button) *- Browsing settings - Font & Layout - Force page to Zoom*.

The fullscreen option is under "Tools"

[image]

[image]

The fact that *the fullscreen only hides the top panel, not the lower buttons* might be a limitation of my device, running Android 10.

---

The same is true for [UC Browser Turbo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ucturbo). This seems to me a more modern, better looking version of UC Browser.

Fit text zoom: *Settings -General - Adapt screen layout style*.

To hide the top bar:  *Settings -General - Show status bar* (un-check). This may not be needed, as the status bar text is dimmed sufficiently in night mode.

Night mode setting is similar to that of UC Browser proper.

For the moment this browser seems the winner to me, as far as this question is concerned, but it needs some fixes, e.g. for example the night mode view is bad on some sites including Wikipedia (it is ok on UC Browser proper) and thus will probably not become my default (although for reading purposes that problem can be fixed with *Settings -General - Text-only*.)

---

Full screen (really "full", hiding main buttons too) can be achieved with applications designed for that purpose, which need [security settings](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) granted by connection to a computer with `adb`. (In this way I can use for example Opera, which has the other two features.) I have tested for the moment [Immersive Fullscreen Mode Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.huseyinatasoy.fullscreen_immersive_mode).